# QT how to use QTableView to display a QMap within a QList

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qtableview, qlist

I am having a QList as follow:

`QList< QMap<QString, QString> > x;`

for example:

`table(1) <name<name(1),ABC> >`

`table(1) <age<age(1),10> >`

I would like to have the "name" and "age" as columns header and down to them the values "ABC" and "10". Next when I have:

`table(1) <name<name(2),DFG> >`

`table(1) <age<age(2),20> >`

the values "DFG" and "20" comes in the next row

so, how can I do make this display ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you have to pass your data to a model and then you can use QTableView to display your data;
to set a model for a table use the following sample:

```
// creating a 4*4 table
QStandardItemModel* table_model = new QStandardItemModel(4, 4);
for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 4; ++column) {
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem((QString())); // you should set your data here (in this case as a string)
        table_model.setItem(row, column, item);
    }
}
```

then you should pass the model to a tableview:

```
QTableView table;
table.setModel(table_model);
table.show();
```

Comment: of course you should set your table on your favorite style ... here I just mentioned an example.

Comment: thanks, it work now, (I also edited your answer, please check it)